# Puppet exec command runs in shell, but not via puppet

Tags: git, bash, automation, puppet, vagrant

I'm trying to use vagrant to set up a dev environment that automatically clones two repositories if they haven't already been cloned.

I wrote a simple script to clone the repos, after failing in many, many ways to get puppet to run the git command directly.  For some reason I thought this method would be foolproof, but it turns out I'm a better fool than I thought.

```
exec {"load-repos":
    command =>"/bin/bash /vagrant/manifests/modules/scripts/clone_repos.sh",
    require => Package["git-core"],
  }
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d /vagrant/repo-one-dest ]; then
  git clone git@example.com:/repo-one.git /vagrant/repo-one-dest
fi

if [ ! -d /vagrant/repo-two-dest ]; then
  git clone git@example.com:/repo-two.git /vagrant/repo-two-dest
fi

exit
```

The private keys are set up properly.  When I log into the vm and manually run `bash clone_repos.sh`, everything works.  No matter how many times I reload vagrant and let puppet do its thing, the repos are never loaded via the exec.  What am I missing?

Comment: Missing space on the first `[` test.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Unfortunatley, that's an artifact I introduced into the post when I replaced the real directory with 'repo-one-dest'.  The script functions correctly when run from the commandline and has the space.  I edited the post to remove the syntax error.

Comment: Adding a 'logoutput=>true," to your Exec block may result in more output that may help with debugging.  

You may also want to add a file["/vagrant/manifests/modules/scripts/clone_repos.sh"] to the require section.  Puppet may be trying to execute the script before puppet's pushed it to your VM.

Comment: I'll try that when I get home tonight.  Fairly 100% positive that it's not an issue with the file not existing on the path, but hey, I've been wrong before.

Comment: BTW: If someone reading this has the time and inclination to solve this problem with a public git repo and post the solution, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because when you `vagrant ssh` you're usually logging in as the `vagrant` user (by default, though this can certainly be modified via configuration). The `vagrant` user I'm guessing has the keys setup properly.

When Vagrant runs your provisioner (Puppet, in this case), however, it does a `sudo`, so it runs as the root user.

The way I generally recommend setting up keys to do the deploy is to put the keys somewhere, and then use a `GIT_SSH` wrapper to properly clone it, or to use SSH agents.

Comment: Good insight.  Not sure if it works, but it seems plausible.  I wound up altering my workflow, and at this point I'm fine with how things are and probably won't go back to my original plan.  If I get some free time I may eventually see if that's the issue.